# How Can I duplicate a section of html code whitout rewrite it each time?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question about HTML/JS development.

So I have an element which represents a section containing some data like job name, localisation.

Those datas come from an SQL table which contains some Job advertisements.

So my question is how can I duplicate this section for each job advertisement whitout rewrite the section each time I call new data from my database.

i hope that it was clear

You can see here my HTML code.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm">
            <section class="py-5">
                <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5 mt-5">
                    <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 row-cols-2 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-xl-4 justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col mb-5">
                            <div class="card h-100">
                                <!-- Product image-->
                                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/450x300/dee2e6/6c757d.jpg" alt="..." />
                                <!-- Product details-->
                                <div class="card-body p-4">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <!-- Product name-->
                                        <h5 class="fw-bolder">
                                            <div id="table-container"></div>
                                        </h5>
                                        <!-- Product price-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
                                        <div class="text-center dropbtn"><a class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto" href="#" onclick="display_h()">Learn More</a></div>
                                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                                      <a href="#">Description</a>
                                      <a href="#">Adresse</a>
                                      <a href="./form.html">Apply</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: [Template engines](https://colorlib.com/wp/top-templating-engines-for-javascript/)?

Comment: Use `<template>` to define the general structure. Then loop through the results of the database query, cloning the template and filling in the details.

Comment: Thank You very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode). From the docs

```js
let p = document.getElementById("para1")
let p_prime = p.cloneNode(true)
```

Comment: Thank You.
I have tried your methods and it works to duplicate my HTML elements.
Unfortunatly, the informations from the data base don't appaer on cloned elements.
Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Well, that's a different thing. I don't know how your code is rendered. If I was doing this in React, for instance, I would have to wait until my component had completed 'layout', so that everything was available in the DOM. But it sounds like you're not really trying to clone/copy an element, so much as provide a template to be filled with the data. This generally requires some kind of framework or templating package.